# why cannot execute Julia script which contains String[] from Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, julia

```
public class ScriptProcess {

    private String[] command;

    public ScriptProcess(String[] c) {
        this.command = c;
    }

    public void exec() {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.command);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){          
                stringBuffer.append(line + " --- ");
            }
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can execute Julia script with this Java class.

For example, here is a julia script:

```
#main.jl
msgTest = Int64[]
push!(msgTest, 1)
push!(msgTest, 2)    
println(msgTest)
```

Then, I can initialize a ScriptProcess to execute the julia script above:

```
String[] command = {"C:\\Julia\\bin\\julia.exe", "C:\\doc\\Julia\\main.jl"};
ScriptProcess sp = new ScriptProcess(command);
sp.exec();
```

Everything's fine, I can get the result: `[1,2]` on the console of eclipse.

However, if I change the `Int64` into `String` for the julia script like this:

```
#main.jl
msgTest = String[]
push!(msgTest, "aaa")
push!(msgTest, "bbb")    
println(msgTest)
```

And I run the same java project, I can't get anything.

However, I can run the julia script with command prompt:

```
C:\> C:\Julia\bin\julia.exe C:\doc\Julia\main.jl
```

I can get the result: `AbstractString["aaa","bbb"]`.

Comment: Off-top: don't use `stringBuffer.append(line + " --- ");` but `stringBuffer.append(line).append(" --- ");`. We are using StringBuilder/Buffer to avoid string concatenation which requires creating additional StringBuilder.

Comment: @Pshemo   thanks. The problem is still there.

Comment: That information wasn't supposed to solve your problem (that is why I posted is as comment and not answer). Purpose of that comment was to show a way to improve part of your code not related to your problem (hence "off-top" note).

Comment: Did you try JuliaCaller for calling Julia scripts from within Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version Julia will generate a warning if `String` is used. `String` has been changed to `AbstractString`.

If we use `String` in Julia or some IDE of Julia, things will still be fine except a warning. However, if we want to execute a julia script with another language project, somehow we can't.

Answer (score 0):

Since not a direct answer to the question, your example code is the base logic under an existing library, namely JuliaCaller, which is distributed with an open source license. You can pass Java objects to Julia, make calculations on the Julia side and get back the result into Java. Here is the link: [JuliaCaller GitHub](https://github.com/jbytecode/juliacaller).

here is an example:

```
List<Double> values = List.of(1.0, 2.0, 10.0, -4.0);
caller.addJuliaObject(JuliaObject.createArrayVariable("a", values));
caller.Execute("using Statistics");
caller.Execute("ave = mean(a)");
double result = caller.getDouble("ave");
assertEquals(2.25, result);
```